# Scraping a simple website with colly in golang does not return any data

Tags: go, web-scraping, go-colly

I'm trying to scrape a simple website that looks like this:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <pre>
    "Name Surname 1
    Name Surname 2
    Name Surname 3
    Name Surname 4"
  </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Wrote a simple go code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

func main() {
    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.AllowedDomains("thewebsite.com"),
    )

    c.OnHTML("body", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        fmt.Println(e.Text)
    })

    c.OnResponse(func(r *colly.Response) {
        fmt.Println(r.StatusCode)
    })

    c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Visiting", r.URL)
    })

    c.Visit("http://thewebsite.com")
}
```

When I run this code, I get the below output:

```
Visiting http://thewebsite.com
200
```

So everything is OK. The website is being opened successfully, but I do not get any data from it.

I've tried to change the `c.OnHTML` to `pre`, `body.pre` - but none of them worked as I expected to.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you mention the website? To check.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I had to remove the domain restriction,  despite it appearing to be correct. In other words, try commenting out the `AllowedDomains()` bit, like this:

```
c := colly.NewCollector(
      //colly.AllowedDomains("thewebsite.com"),
    )
```

Comment: This works for me too, but this method is essential, any ideas on how to use the method correctly?